# Pull webpage information to text box

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

So what I am trying to do is pull some data from a webpage, and put it into a text box. Online, I can find alot about doing it the other way around (putting text box into web) but none the way I want.

I have gotten this far... (not very) and have no clue where to go from here

```
Dim Helement As HtmlElement

    Helement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtAddress1")
    Helement.GetAttribute()
```

Here is the element from the browser I am trying to use

```
input#ctl00_m_g_79f90d63_a5eb_43e1_9403_69fefa0ba004_ctl00_txtAddress1
```

Thanks guys!

This is what I tried:

```
Dim Helement As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtAddress1")
    Dim elementtype As String = Helement.GetAttribute("text")
    Dim textContents As String = Helement.InnerText

    Address.Text = textContents
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GetAttribute` function will return the value of an attribute of the element you retrieved using `GetElementById`.

For example, something like:

```
<input type="text" id="txtAddress1">

Dim Helement as HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("txtAddress1")
Dim elementType as String = Helement.GetAttribute("type")
Dim textContents as String = Helement.InnerText
```

[InnerText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innertext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN

[GetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) MSDN

Comment: I updated top post with what I tried - with no luck. Can you see what I messed up with

Comment: If this program is working with a third party site rather than one you're generating, I think you may have to use the entirety of the ID rather than just the `txtAddress1` bit